# Написание редактора блога для сайта (WYSIWYG)

Tags: java, html, css, spring

Подскажите редактор, который я мог бы добавить себе на сайт для того, чтобы я мог создавать в нем статьи. Нужен похожий редактор как у StackOverflow (WMD) и желательно ссылка на установку редактора на сервак/в код

Редактор должен поддерживать подгрузку на сайт изображений!

Я пишу на Spring(Java), поэтому плагины к WordPress или что-то для npm и Node.js не предлагать

Comment: Это называется WYSIWYG HTML редактор, сложно было найти когда не знал что искать, вот ссылка на 10 популярных, https://1stwebdesigner.com/best-wysiwyg-html-editor/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На данный момент я нашел пару WYSIWYG редакторов. Но из всех них я остановился на [Quill Editor](https://quilljs.com/).

Редактор очень простой и **не требует установки дополнительного контента на сервер**. Вот пример самого редактора:

```js
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: {
    imageResize: {
      displaySize: true
    },
    toolbar: [
      [{
        header: [1, 2, 3, false]
      }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      [{
        list: 'ordered'
      }, {
        list: 'bullet'
      }],
      ['clean'],
      ['link', 'image']
    ]
  },
  placeholder: 'Здесь пишем наш текст...',
  theme: 'snow'
});
```

```html
<!-- Include the Quill library -->
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/kensnyder/quill-image-resize-module/3411c9a7/image-resize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="editor"></div>
```

Примеры отправки формы, документация и другие фишки данного редактора вы найдете на официальном сайте.